# HDFS Space Assignment (Size / Used / Available)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I read some references but I still cannot figure out clearly how the basic total size available to store files on the HDFS system is determined.

If I have a 1TB Disk with HDFS service running will the dfs part "grow" naturally as I add files to it, or is there a part of the disk that is assigned to the DFS by default ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the disk usage for HDFS will **grow** as the files are added to it.
By default, Datanodes will try to use all of the space available in their storage directories `dfs.datanode.data.dir`.

Configured Capacity of a Datanode is

```
Total Storage Capacity - Reserved Storage
```

`Reserved Storage` is **`0B`** by default. If you wish to reserve some space on the storage for non-HDFS usage, add this property in the `hdfs-site.xml` of the datanodes

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.du.reserved</name>
  <value>107374182400</value> <!-- 100 GB reserved -->
  <description>Reserved space in bytes per volume. Always leave this much space free for non dfs use</description>
</property>
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you be kind to have a look to this other related question please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43165646/hdfs-space-usage-on-fresh-install