# HDFS space usage on fresh install

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I just installed  HDFS and launched the service,
and there is already more than 800MB of used space.

What does it represent ?

```
$ hdfs dfs -df -h
Filesystem                         Size     Used  Available  Use%
hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020  54.5 G  823.7 M     43.4 G    1%
```

Comment: It is possible that some files were uploaded into hdfs as part of quickstart VM installation. Can you post the output of `hdfs dfs -du -h /`

Comment: `1.3 G  1.3 G  /user` looks like the user folder is where data is. 
How can I access the /user directory ? I am a bit lost, sorry

Comment: Do a recursive listing on `/user`. Try this command `hdfs dfs -ls -R /user`

Comment: Ok, the oozie jars were the one taking most space :)
However, I still can't access to the "/user" directory (No such file or directory
) although the hdfs dfs -ls lists it (example : `/user/oozie/share/lib/sqoop/sqoop.jar` )

Comment: Suspected it would be `Oozie ShareLib`! What do you mean by can't access? I see that you are able to read the contents of `/user`.